# How can I use ffmpeg on PythonAnywhere?

Tags: python, ffmpeg, pythonanywhere, echonest

I'm trying to make a web app with Flask, hosted on [PythonAnywhere](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/), which will use the [Echo Nest Remix](https://echonest.github.io/remix/python.html) library.

The problem is that **Remix uses ffmpeg** and **PythonAnywhere only has avconv**.

Is there any way I can use ffmpeg on PythonAnywhere?

I'm using PythonAnywhere's free account if it makes a difference.

Thank you!

Comment: just to clarify, do you mean that echo nest remix doesn't work right now because ffmpeg is not installed? Or that nest remix somehow tries to use avconv but fails because it was expecting ffmpeg?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem? If so, could you please share some details on how you did that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing we can do about that short term. The two executables have a similar interface (though it's not entirely the same), so you may be able to create a symlink for ffmpeg somewhere on your path to avconv and it *may* work.

Answer (score 1):

there'a another workaround almost similar to the above, I presume that you have set up a virtual environment. On the bin directory of your virtual env, copy the ffmpeg and ffprobe binaries.

the two binaries can be got from your system, if you had installed them, by typing

```
    which ffmpeg
```

and

```
    which ffprobe
```

respectively.

the idea is that both ffmpeg and avconv use the same interface, and as such by simply pointing to an ffmpeg binary, it can take it from there with the other avconv files,